Preservation of affineness of open Subsets of a scheme under automorphism by a group element due to a group acting on a scheme.

Now during the proof they used a result that if $U\subset X$ an open affine subset and $g\in G$, then $\sigma_{g}(U)$ is open affine set. Then, they use the result that in a separated scheme, the intersection of affine open subsets is open. Now openness is apparent as $g\in Aut(G)$. But I can not find a clue about affineness. Sorry if this is a trivial question. But I am stuck. Thank you.

First note that $\sigma_g$ is an isomorphism by definition of a group action. This implies that $\sigma_g$ restricted to $U$ is an isomorphism from $U$ to $\sigma_g(U)$. Since $U$ is affine, this implies that $\sigma_g(U)$ is affine.

So, here you mean the image of an affine open set is affine. If yes, may I know why? Sorry for asking.

@AnubhabPahari $\sigma_g:U\to \sigma_g(U)$ is an isomorphism, and the property of being an affine scheme is an isomorphism invariant: a scheme $X$ is affine iff $X\cong\operatorname{Spec} \mathcal{O}_X(X)$.

So, $\sigma_{g}(U)$ is isomorphic to $Spec \mathscr(O)_{X}(X)$. Nice! Thank you as usual.
